# Не могу понять , почему данная программа не видит массив COLOR

Tags: python, графы, локальные-переменные

Пробовал разными способами массив COLOR: добавлял сам массив за пределами функции и в самой ,делал ее глобальной ,но все время он выдает ошибку -> name 'COlOR' is not defined.Программа делает обход в глубину с раскраской для нахождения компонент связностей)))
Вот код:

```
N , M = list(map(int , input().split()))
chart_adjacent = [[] for i in range(0 , N)]
list_visit = list()
for i in range(0 , M):
    u , v = list(map(int , input().split()))
    chart_adjacent[u - 1].append(v)
    chart_adjacent[v - 1].append(u)
for j in chart_adjacent:
    j = j.sort()
start = 1
COLOR = [0]*(N + 1)
color_number = 0
def DFS(start , chart_adjacent , color_number):#depth- first search
    global COLOR
    COlOR[start] = color_number
    for i in chart_adjacent[start]:
        if i == 0:
            DFS(i , chart_adjacent , color_number)

for start in COLOR:
    if COLOR[start] ==0:
        color_number += 1
        DFS(start , chart_adjacent , color_number)
print(COLOR)
```

Comment: У вас существует только массив `COLOR`, а массива `COlOR` у вас нету

Comment: И вот это `for start in COLOR:` так работать не будет, надо будет заменить на `for start in range(len(COLOR)):`

Comment: @CrazyElf почему не будет?

Comment: @YaAlex Потому что дальше по коду там `start` используется как индекс в списке, а не как элемент списка. Ну то есть в данном контексте нужен другой цикл `for`, так то конструкция `for x in y` вполне легальная и более питонячая по духу, чем с `for i in range(len(`

Answer (score 1):

`COLOR` и `COlOR` разные переменные, а с первого раза и не видно...)

Answer (score 0):

Буква C была русской.Из-за этого программа и не видела массив COLOR!!!